# python script that queries sql db AND postfix server to report mail send failure

Tags: python, sql, smtp

I have a service running that builds reports and attaches them to postfix email.  If reports are BUILT successfully a status is sent to the db.  Obviously mail output goes to mail.log.  I need to write a python script (run as a cron job) that will query the db for the status and then parse mail.log for "Relay Access Denied" and compare the db result with the mail.log result to discern if a report has failed to send.  I don't have a ton of experience with python or sql so I'm wondering if anyone knows any good ways to write this to help get me started.  I've looked online but there isn't a lot.  If there is a better way to do this feel free to let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: usually you start with *some* code ... and when you get stuck with *some* code you come here and ask a question that has a definitive answer.... if for some reason that is just not possible then at a minimum you need to tell us which kind of SQL it is, you also would need to show us what a successful entry in the database looks like and what the actual contents of mail.log look like ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I think this is a worthy question to ask and one that's important for the stack's records because I wasn't able to find any content on this topic on the internet.